# How can I add Clang toolchain in my CLion IDE?

Tags: c++, clang, clion

I have installed LLVM 12.0.0 win-64 in my Win-10 machine.

The following is my CLion 2019.3 configuration window for the compiler toolchain:

[image]

I don't see Clang or LLVM option here.

How can I add Clang in my CLion IDE?

**P.S.** Are MinGW and Clang the same or different toolchains?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most common setups are handled in this section: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-tutorial-on-configuring-clion-on-windows.html
On Windows, you install Visual Studio with the Clang components.

Comment: The statement _On Windows you use MinGW if you want to use Clang._ is not true.  You install Visual Studio with the clang components instead.  MinGW != clang.